# Trace and Norm of Primitive element

Tags: field-theory, algebraic-number-theory

Suppose that $K$ is a number field, that is a finite extension of $\mathbb{Q}$. By the primitive element theorem, we can find a $\xi$ such that $K=\mathbb{Q}(\xi)$. Is there a quick formula for the trace and norm of $\xi$ ?

Comment: A quick formula in terms of what? What is your description of $K$? Of $\xi$ (which is by no means unique)?

Comment: @CaptainLama I have added an answer. The answer I was probably looking for was in terms of the minimal polynomial for $\xi$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe the following was what I had in my mind when I asked the question.

Suppose $K$ is a degree $n$ extension of $\mathbb{Q}$ and suppose that
$$
\xi^n = a_0 + a_1\xi + a_2\xi^2 + \ldots + a_{n-1}\xi^{n-1}
$$ for some rational numbers $a_i$ s. Then we know that $\{1, \xi, \xi^2,\ldots,\xi^{n-1}\}$ is a vector space basis for $K$ over $\mathbb{Q}$. By definition, the trace of $\xi$ is the trace of the $\mathbb{Q}$ linear map $x\mapsto \xi x$ from $K$ to $K$. Therefore by considering the matrix representation of this map with the basis mentioned above, we can see that
$$
1\mapsto \xi\\
\xi\mapsto \xi^2\\
\vdots\\
\xi^{n-1}\mapsto f(\xi).
$$

Then the matrix of the above linear transformation is given by

$$
\begin{pmatrix}
0 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_0\\
1 & 0 & 0 & \cdots & a_1\\
0 & 1 & 0 & \cdots & a_2\\
\vdots & \vdots & \vdots & \ddots & \vdots\\
0 & 0 & 0 & \ldots & a_{n-1}
\end{pmatrix}.
$$

So the trace is equal to $a_{n-1}$. Evaluating along the first row, the determinant of the matrix is $\pm a_0$ which is the norm.

Comment: Your computations are correct, so if you were looking for a formula in terms of the minimal polynomial I think you can accept your own answer.